# Define a sign of Int when it's zero and negative-zero

Tags: swift

I have a value of `Int` type. I need to define a sign of this value. And I don't know how to handle edge-case with `-0`.

> **signum** - returns -1 if this value is negative and 1 if it’s positive;
>   otherwise, 0

```
0.signum()  // 0
-0.signum() // 0
```

I tried to convert it to `Double`, but also it didn't help.

```
Double(-0).floatingPointClass == .negativeZero // false
```

And to `String`

```
String(-0) // "0"
```

Is there any solution for this problem ? Or `0` and `-0` of `Int` type is the same values ?

Comment: The `signup` definition doesn't say that there is `-0` at all. Zero is neither negative nor positive.

Comment: @vadian but Swift standard library has classes that handle this scenario, but it only for floats. `(-0.0).floatingPointClass == .negativeZero // true`. I don't understand why there is no for `Int`.

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander, in a floating point number, there is a separate sign bit.  In an `Int` with its 2's complement representation, there is no sign bit.  You can't change an `Int` from positive to negative by just flipping a sign bit.  There is no way to represent `0` and `-0` as distinct values in an `Int`.

Comment: BTW, `-3.signum()` isn't doing what you think it is.  It first calls `signum()` on `3` and then negates the result it gets back.

Comment: @vacawama you are right, (-3).signum() is correct expression

Comment: [See for yourself.](https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/61bc8a8a1614ec6fae2b0e912b31db79) Here are all the numbers representable by 8 bits, interpreted as a signed or unsigned integer. Notice how 0 only occurs once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done.  `0` and `-0` do not have separate representations as an `Int`.  Integers in Swift (as in other programming languages) use [`2`'s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.  To negate a number, you invert all of the bits and add `1`.  Starting with the `Int` `0`, all bits are `0`.  Inverting all of the bits results in all `1`'s, and then adding `1` causes it to go back to all `0`'s as the carry bit rolls off the top.  So `0` and `-0` have the exact same representation.